# Not able to set fuzziness as auto in MultiMatch Query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am trying to use a multimatch query by instantiating an object of the following type:

```
MultiMatchQuery query = new MultiMatchQuery()
            {
                Query = searchString,
                Fuzziness = 6, //TODO Need to set AUTO Here
                Fields = new PropertyPathMarker[] { "title", "hTexts.htext", "tnText" }
            });
```

As seen above, I am setting fuzziness to 6, but I need to set it to auto. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet possible, but pretty soon in version 2.0.0: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/941